# Введение данных в json файл

Tags: php, json

У меня есть вопрос по введению данных в json файл.
Вообщем, мне нужно, что бы json файл хранил в себе часть кода, ид видеозаписи, ид пользователя, название видео и описание видео. Думаю, если сделать массив таким (php):

```
$array = 
    ["idv: " => $idv,
     "idp: " => $idp,
     "src: " => $src,
     "desc: " => $desc,
     "vname: " => $vname];
```

Думаю, будет следующее - один пользователь добавляет видеозапись, она сохраняется, НО как только другой пользователь добавляет новую видеозапись - значения обновляются и от старой не остаётся и следа.
Как решить эту проблему? Думаю, что можно сделать что то вроде

```
["".$idv.""=> [
         "idp: " => $idp,
         "src: " => $src,
         "desc: " => $desc,
         "vname: " => $vname]];
```

Тогда, как я могу получить значения idp, src, desc, vname, если $idp равен, к примеру 3? Не уверен, что понятно сформулировал вопрос, так что отвечу, если что не ясно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у тебя проблема с добавлением элементов в `JSON` на php.
Для начала тебе нужно сделать массив:

```
$arr = array();
array_push($arr, array("idv: " => $idv,
     "idp: " => $idp,
     "src: " => $src,
     "desc: " => $desc,
     "vname: " => $vname
));
```

Далее нужно запихнуть массив в `JSON`:

```
json_encode($arr);
```

Чтобы записать в `JSON` новый элемент можно перевести его обратно в массив:

```
json_decode($arr, true);
```

Как добавить новый элемент в массив и переобразовать в `JSON` смотри выше. На выходе получится структура:

```
[ 0=> [ "idp: " => "1",
        "src: " => "path",
        "desc: " => "description",
        "vname: " => "name"
],1 => ["idp: " => "2",
        "src: " => "path2",
        "desc: " => "description2",
        "vname: " => "name2"
       ]
]
```